# how to write sql query? for ms sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a sql query that adds one column from one database (DB1) to another column and the sum is save in that column in the second database(DB2). where userIds are the same

```
DB1
TableA
UserId People


DB2
TableB
Amount UserId
```

it would be something like this

DB2.TableB.Amount = DB2.TableB.Amount + DB1.TableA.People

Comment: Please specify platform (SQL Server, Oracle, whatever)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
UPDATE b
SET    Amount = b.Amount + a.People
FROM DB2.dbo.TableB b
INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.TableA a
  ON  a.UserId = b.UserId
```

dbo = owner of table, it can also be unspecified: DB1..TableA

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.TableB
SELECT COUNT(*), UserID
FROM DB1.dbo.TableA
GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested:

```
INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.TableB
SELECT SUM(DB2.TableB.Amount + DB1.TableA.People), UserID
FROM DB1.dbo.TableA
GROUP BY UserID
```